# PHP json encoded string escaping

Tags: php, json

I need to escape json encoded string.

I have `encode` below string.

```
json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''])
```

It will store in `mysql` table like,

```
"{\"test1\":\"\",\"test2\":\"\",\"test3\":\"\"}"
```

I want to store like,

```
{"test":"","test2":"","test3":""}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Why don't just decode it when you fetch it? since it's a json, you still need to decode it even though you didn't want to escape it when inserting on a database.

Comment: use stripslashes

Comment: https://eval.in/929761

Comment: I think there's a misconception about escaping here. You really don't need to store it escaped.

Comment: Also what's the link between what you encode and what you store? These are 2 completely different objects (amazingly enough, replicated as is in the so call solutions, lol)

Comment: @Capsule please see my edited question.

Comment: It's better but it still doesn't change the fact you don't need to store it escaped. Just store it as is and decode it when you read it from the DB. That question is not a real one, you are just trying to solve an issue that is not one in the first place, in a convoluted way on top of that.

Comment: @JaydeepMor use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` before saving DB. So all fine

Comment: @AbdullaNilam JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES = Don't escape /. There's no forward slashes in the string to be stored, just quotes.

Comment: @Capsule I don't know what you trying to say. Read the post **I want to store like, `{"test":"","test2":"","test3":""}`**. So what? As mentioned [on Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072735/4595675) OP can do it when saving. And what you trying to say replace `/\` ?? there is no `\` when you saved with as i said already.

Comment: Yes, so what? the output of `json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''])` can be stored as is, there's nothing else needed.

Comment: If you're talking about DB escaping / prepared statement and anything DB related, then that's another story, but adding parameters to the json_encode function won't solve any of these.

Comment: @Capsule you are right. 

AbdullaNilam please check by storing in DB not echoing.

Comment: @JaydeepMor use variable to store and save

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
<?php
$json = json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => '']);
$dbjson = "{\"title\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"keywords\":\"\"}";

echo "<pre>";
$value = json_encode(json_decode($dbjson));
print_r($value); // output : {"title":"","description":"","keywords":""}
?>
```

Comment: You need to escape quotes to write your string, but the actual string doesn't contain the escape characters so the decode/encode is just a waste of time and you could just print $dbjson and get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Add [`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) as last argument

```
echo json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''],JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

Output

```
{"test1":"","test2":"","test3":""}
```

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES won't escape forward slashes, I don't see any link with the original question

Comment: @Capsule Who said to escape slash. It's before saving DB.

Comment: `json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''],JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)` and `json_encode(['test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''])` will both output exactly the same string: `{"test1":"","test2":"","test3":""}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function

```
$string = '{\"title\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"keywords\":\"\"}';
echo stripslashes($string);
```

And also you can Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
 $string = '{\"title\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"keywords\":\"\"}';
 echo $new_str = preg_replace('~[\\\\/*?<>|]~', '', $string);
?>
```

Output :

```
{ "title ": "", "description ": "", "keywords ": ""}
```

Comment: Nice copy [Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48072742/revisions). In your first answer you're showing `{ "title ": "", "description ": "", "keywords ": ""}` and second one `'test1' => '','test2' => '','test3' => ''`

Comment: Now it's fine ? @AbdullaNilam :)

Comment: Basically, rewriting http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php?

Comment: Thanks @Capsule, Right Stripslashes function is use for that.